# How to write java classes representing json object with subobjects?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

```
{
    "car" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "year" : "2015",
        "Activities" : [
            {"activeDate" : "2019", "drivenBy" : "Jimmy"},
            {"activeDate" : "2018", "drivenBy" : "Sam"}
        ],
        "maker" : "GM"
    }
}
```

I would like to write Java Class that represents the above JSON object to use it on my rest API request. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: have you tried anything ? at least some effort of code ?

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 3):

Everything inside a pair of curly brackets can be seen as a java object. If you have square brackets then that means that you have a list and the simple properties are basic objects like strings, ints and so on.

So, for example:

```
{
    "house" : {
        "noRooms" : 3,
        "rooms" : [
            {"name" : "kitchen", "surface" : 10.5 },
            {"name" : "bathroom", "surface" : 5 },
            {"name" : "bedroom", "surface" : 12.3 }
        ]
    }
}
```

In this, because you start with a pair of curly brackets you have your first object, which you can name whatever you want. For lack of a better name, I'll call mine **Building**.

Inside this building I have a property named **house**. Because this is specified by curly brackets it means we will need another object. We'll call this **House**.

Going deeper we see two properties of **House**: the number of rooms called **noRooms** and something called **rooms** which appears to be a list (notice the square brackets).

For the number of rooms, we don't need to create a different object as most frameworks/utilities know how to deal with this so, an integer will do just fine. For the things inside the list we will need special objects that we will call **Room**.

These objects have two properties, a **name** which translates into a **string** and a **surface** which could be a **double**.

So, your classes would look something like:

```
public class Building {
    private House house;
    //rest of the code
}

public class House {
    private int noRooms;
    private List<Room> rooms;
    //rest of the code
}

public class Room {
    private String name;
    private double surface;
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I am using very similar thing as yours but Room is not setting any values for me

Comment: what tool/framework are you using to make the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Jackson as your serializer, you'll be needing three classes to perform the serialization/deserialization based on the example JSON object you provided:

```
public class ActivityResource {

    private String activeDate;
    public String getActiveDate() { return activeDate; }
    public void setActiveDate(String activeDate) { this.activeDate = activeDate; }

    private String drivenBy;
    public String getDrivenBy() { return drivenBy; }
    public void setDrivenBy(String drivenBy) { this.drivenBy = drivenBy; }

}
```

Followed by this:

```
public class CarResource {

    private String color;
    public String getColor() { return color; }
    public void setColor(String color) { this.color = color; }

    private String year;
    public String getYear() { return year; }
    public void setYear(String year) { this.year = year; }

    @JsonProperty("Activities")
    private List<ActivityResource> activities;
    public List<ActivityResource> getActivities() { return activities; }
    public void setActivities(List<ActivityResource> activities) { this.activities = activities; }

    private String maker;
    public String getMaker() { return maker; }
    public void setMaker(String maker) { this.maker = maker; }

}
```

And finally this:

```
public class CarRequestResource {

    private CarResource car;
    public CarResource getCar() { return car; }
    public void setCar(CarResource car) { this.car = car; }

}
```

With all these in place you'll be able to deserialize the request with no problems.

Comment: Hi. I was using the similar thing but I just used your code but the request body shows null value for  "Activities" : null  when making the {
    "car" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "year" : "2015",
        "Activities" : [
            {"activeDate" : "2019", "drivenBy" : "Jimmy"},
            {"activeDate" : "2018", "drivenBy" : "Sam"}
        ],
        "maker" : "GM"
    }
}

Comment: As long as your JSON contains a field named `Activities` it should deserialize correctly. Can you please share your request example?

Comment: {
    "car" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "year" : "2015",
        "Activities" : [
            {"activeDate" : "2019", "drivenBy" : "Jimmy"},
            {"activeDate" : "2018", "drivenBy" : "Sam"}
        ],
        "maker" : "GM"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the json you've posted, we're going to call the Java class **Car**.
Car has four attributes: color, year, activities, and maker.

You can simply find the datatype of each attribute by reviewing the json file. In this case, we have *color*, *year* and *maker* fields as strings and the *activities* is a list.

To define the list, it's better to create another class named "Activity" with two attributes: activeDate and driveBy (which are both strings)

```
public class Activity {
    private String activityDate;
    private String drivenBy;
    ...
}
```

Make sure to add constructors, getters and setters as well.

```
public class Car {
    private String color;
    private String year;
    private List<Activity> activities;
    private String maker;
    ...
}
```

There are several online tools to convert json files to Java classes, but I suggest you learn the basics and do it yourself in the future to make sure that you don't get stuck in the middle of a more complicated project.

Here is an interesting article helping you get familiar with it:
[dzone.com:introduction-to-json-with-java](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-json-with-java)